# Updating rows of dynamic MySQL table using user input

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

**UPDATE:** for some reason the php file won't read the mysqli_query statment.

I have a dynamically filled table that has an input box to input a certain quantity amount in order to move a part to a different location with that quantity. Right now I am just trying to get the update code to work to update the current amount based on the inputted amount. Eventually I will add the ability to insert a new row into MySQL based on the inputted amount and inputted location.

It seems to be accessing the update.php file but have had no luck in the MySQL database being updated. I'm not sure how to send the data to the php file in order to update the appropriate rows.

This is my webpage:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>




<?php

if (isset($_GET['Placeid'])){

$moveplace = $_GET['Placeid'];
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM Parts p, Locations l
        WHERE Placeid = '$moveplace' and p.locationid = l.locationid";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($queryResult > 0){

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
<form onsubmit='updatetable()'
<table  id='tablerun' class=searcht style='background-color:$bgcolor'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td id='row1' value='".$row['id']."' name='moveid' style='display:none'>".$row['id']."</td>
          <td value='".$row['PartNum']."' name='movepart'>".$row['PartNum']."</td>
          <td value='".$row['ModelNum']."' name='movemodelnum'>".$row['ModelNum']."</td>
          <td>".$row['Country']."</td>
          <td>".$row['Region']."</td>
          <td>".$row['Location']."</td>
          <td>".$row['Placeid']."</td>
          <td style='width:100px' value='".$row['UnitNum']."' name='moveunitnum'>".$row['UnitNum']."</td>
          <td id='val' style='width:50px;' value='".$row['QTY']."' name='moveqty'>".$row['QTY']."</td>
          <td value='0' type=text id='amt' name='moveamt'></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>";

}
echo "<tr><td></td><td><input type='submit' class='submit' ></td></tr></form>";
}
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function updatetable(){

  $('#tablerun tr').each(function(){
    var row_id = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();
    var quantity = $(this).find("td:eq(8)").text();
    var amt = $(this).find("input:eq(0)").val();

    var data = {
      id : row_id,
      qty : quantity,
      amt : amt
      };

    $.ajax({
    type:   "POST",
    url:    "update.php",
    data:   data,
    success: function() {
        $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
        $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
      }
    });
  });
};

</script>
```

update.php:

```
<?php

include_once 'includes/database.inc.php';

$id = $_POST['moveid'];
$qty = $_POST['moveqty'];
$amt = $_POST['moveamt'];

  $sql = "UPDATE parts set QTY = $qty - $amt where id = $id";

  mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));


 ?>
```

P.S. I realize that I should be using prepared statements I plan on implementing them once I have completed this task. 
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Turn on error reporting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5438060/296555 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/14578243/296555. That should help you get a few steps closer.

Comment: I'm not getting any error messages. Does it look like this should be working?

Comment: I figured it out. The 'id' I was getting wasn't the id number in the table, just the part name. So it wouldn't update due to it not being a primary key. I needed to change the td:eq(1) to (0).